# Query Linux Package Database with Python

Tags: python, linux, package, rpm, deb

I need a python library to query the database of installed rpm/deb packages.

Usage1: check if package "foo" is installed.

Usage2: check if package "foo" with version>=1.0 is installed.

Not needed: check which packages could be installed, install packages, ....

I tried google and pypi, but failed. But maybe I am blind.

Answer (score 0):

To query the rpm packages using yum you can use the example from here:

[Given an rpm package name, query the yum database for updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489113/given-an-rpm-package-name-query-the-yum-database-for-updates)

and another example for fedora:

http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/ch16s03s02.html

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/querying-with-the-rpm-python-api-560240/

and here how to get the version:

[How do I compare Rpm versions in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206319/how-do-i-compare-rpm-versions-in-python)

or here another method to do the comparison:

http://concisionandconcinnity.blogspot.com.es/2008/12/rpm-style-version-comparison-in-python.html