# How do I perform a "yum update" using the Yumbase Python module?

Tags: python, yum

Edit: So apparantly my install wasn't working. This pointed me to a mailing list [Here](http://lists.baseurl.org/pipermail/yum-devel/2013-November/010425.html) where I figured out which commands I was missing. I have the answer for the update below. Now that I think about it, it does make sense. I just wish they'd put this somewhere simple on the dev pages.

```
yb = yum.YumBase()
yb.conf.assumeyes = True

yb.update(name='aws-cli')
yb.buildTransaction()
yb.processTransaction()
```

I'm trying to perform an update using yumbase when a server first boots with my kickstart script. At the moment I have a rather crude python subprocess to do "yum update" and would like to make this better.

I'm trying to hook into Yumbase, but the documentation is quite scarce. I have had a look at both the source code and documentation on this page: http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/5MinuteExamples

I've figured out how to list all packages but not the ones that need updating using an SO answer from 2008: [Given an rpm package name, query the yum database for updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489113/given-an-rpm-package-name-query-the-yum-database-for-updates/490410#490410?newreg=02f9277347fa4662a5c2d400e7fe7c32)

I've also figured out it's a very simple 3-line process to install a new package:

```
yb = yum.YumBase()
yb.conf.assumeyes = True
yb.install(name='aws-cli')
```

However the following doesn't work to "update" the package:

```
yb = yum.YumBase()
yb.conf.assumeyes = True
yb.update(name='aws-cli')
```

So what I need is:

1: A way to list the packages that need updating, much like "yum check-update"

2: Install the packages above using "yum update"

Comment: What's wrong with the "crude python subprocess"? From what I can see in the code, it doesn't seem to be written to be used as a library. The code you gave is not the right way to do it: you miss e.g. obtaining the global lock.

Comment: If you just want to update all packages with available updates that's the default update behaviour. You shouldn't need to specify any packages at all and should just be `yb.update()` I think.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in the `yum` code, it doesn't seem to be written to be used as a library. The code you gave is not the right way to do it, there's much else happening behind the scenes.

Basically, as of `yum-3.4.3`, the process looks like this:

```
->yummain.__main__
<trap KeyboardInterrupt>
->yummain.user_main(sys.argv[1:], exit_code=True)
 <check YUM_PROF,YUM_PDB envvars, wrap the following into debugger/profiler if set>
 ->yummain.main(args)
  <set up locale, set up logging>
  -><create a YumBaseCli (child of YumBase & YumOutput)>
   <incl. fill a list field with YumCommand instances of known commands>
  ->cli.YumBaseCli.getOptionsConfig()
   <parse args into the YumBaseCli instance, includes initializing plugins>
  <obtain global yum lock>
  <check write permissions for current dir>
  ->cli.YumBaseCli.doCommands()
   <select a YumCommand from the list>
   ->YumCommand.needTs/needTsRemove if needed
   ->YumCommand.doCommand(self, self.basecmd, self.extcmds)
  <handle errors & set error code if any>
  'Resolving Dependencies'
  ->cli.YumBaseCli.buildTransaction()
   <check for an unfinished transaction>
   <resolve deps using the info written by the YumCommand into the object>
   <honor clean_requirements_on_remove, protected_packages,
    protected_multilib, perform some checks>
  <handle errors & set error code if any>
  'Dependencies Resolved'
  ->cli.YumBaseCli.doTransaction()
   <download, transaction check, transaction test, transaction
   using the info in the object>
  <handle errors & set error code if any>
  'Complete!'
  <release global yum lock>
 sys.exit(error_code)
```

As you can see, the main working sequence is embedded directly into `main` so you can only replicate this logic in-process by running it directly:

```
 yummain.main(<sequence of cmdline arguments>)
```

Which is just the same as running a separate process minus process isolation.

Comment: `yum` the tool is not `yum` the python module. The python module is what the cli uses underneath.

Comment: @EtanReisner These findings show that though you can use the module, in order to perform an action correctly (the same way a tool does), you need to replicate all this logic which is so taxing that it defeats the principle.

Comment: I don't believe you need anywhere near all that code and can quite likely just steal and use `doTransaction` after the `update()` call but I would have to test it to be sure. (At very least going through the options/command/etc. bit should be entirely unnecessary for this purpose.) It is certainly more complicated than would be nice however.

Comment: Well, you can try and report your findings. I elaborated on the sequence somewhat so you get a little better picture on how much is hardcoded into the main routines. And this is not even `YumBase`, the latter's docstring says it's *"almost an abstract class in that you will need to add your own class above it for most real use".*